# Using lmer to analyze mixed model with multiple random effects in R?

Tags: r, lme4, anova, nlme

A re-edit to my previous post. I tried in cross validated but was closed due to coding inquiry.

I'm currently trying to find the best way to analyze whether habitat restoration treatments affect arthropod family richness on a sand dune ecosystem and am having trouble determining the random effects and fixed effects in my model and the proper model to run that will allow be to do a post-hoc test.

Two treatments (herbicide and mechanical removal) and a control were conducted on 9 randomized blocks within a preserve. Each block contains three plots (ex., 1H, 1S, 1C -> Block 1; 2H, 2S, 2C -> Block 2). And each block/plot was sampled twice in two different sessions (sess), Spring or Summer to account for the temporal difference in insect type activity, although I'm not really interested in between session information. There are a total of 54 data points where I received different numbers for my Families response variable.

Spring session x 9 blocks x 3 plots each = 27 plots, Summer session x 9 blocks x 3 plots each = 27 plots

Other factors that could be affecting arthropod composition could be abiotic factors like side (Side) of the sand dune preserve (East side - at the top of the ridge with larger sand particles or West side - lower elevation and similar to ground level with smaller sand particles). Also aspect (Aspect) in reference to sun direction. Some of the plots are facing N, others facing S, E, or W.

With my understanding, the response variable would be family richness (Families), the independent variable would be treatment (Treat), and random/confounding factors would be Block, Plot, and Aspect since those were not controlled? I'm not too sure about whether Side being fixed or random in my case.

I think Plot could be nested in Block.

Fixed effects: Treatment; Random effects: Block, Plot, Aspect; Side is unknown but I am leaning towards fixed effect.

I tried to do a linear model using lmer and following that with a post-hoc test, but I'm not too sure if this is the right result because of my statistical interpretation of the fixed and random effects.

```
lme <-lmer(Families~Treat + (1 |blck/plt ) + (1|Aspect) + (1|Side), data=df)
 summary(lme)
library(multcomp)
 summary(glht(lme, linfct = mcp(Treat = "Tukey")), test = adjusted("holm"))
```

Any help on whether the input is a correct model, or if I'm understanding my variables incorrectly would be greatly appreciated. Also would this be a proper post-hoc test to look at differences?

Thank you.

I tried an Anova, Lmer, lm and I'm still a bit confused on how to add multiple random effects in my code and get a proper pairwise comparison.

Comment: I really think this belongs on CV (and am voting to close), but I'm answering here anyway to spare you the hassle of being bounced between sites without an answer yet again ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```r
Families ~ Treat + Aspect + Side + (1 |blck/plt )
```

- two reasons you want `Aspect` and `Side` to be fixed rather than random are (1) conceptually, (for example) N/S/E/W are not *exchangeable* values, and you're not trying to generalize to other aspects; (2) practically, random effects with only 2 (`Side`) or 4 (`Aspect`) levels are hard to fit.
- since this is a *randomized block design*, you would want typically to allow for the variation of treatment effects across plots (i.e. `1|blck/plt/Treat`); however, since you (IUIC) a single observation of each treatment in each plot, this variation would be confounded with the residual variation anyway, so `1|blck/plt` is appropriate.

- the Tukey test is fine, but rather than look at all pairwise comparisons I would encourage you to think about the following set of contrasts, following the "Custom contrasts and linear functions" section of the relevant [emmeans vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#linfcns):

  - control vs. average treatment effect `((H+S)/2 - C)`
  - herbicide vs. mechanical (`H-S`)
    If your factor is ordered `C`, `H`, `S` I think this would be specified in `emmeans` as `list(avgtrt = c(-1, 1/2, 1/2), trtdiff = c(0, 1, -1))`.

The advantages of choosing meaningful contrasts in advance are (1) by convention, people don't expect you to do multiplicity corrections; (2) it is slightly harder to fall into the trap of overinterpreting a large number of significant/NS outcomes, although in this case there are only three pairwise comparisons anyway, so it might not make as much difference.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. I just read through the vignette and tried inputting my data similar to how you mentioned, and it is providing the information that I have been trying to get for the past week. I initially did have the Aspect and Side as random effects, but was also adding interactions which was making my code difficult and I sort of gave up with that approach. I'll read more about emmeans and custom contrasts for more in-depth analysis. Much appreciated!

Comment: If this solved your problem, you're encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...